# Object created after reading from json file uses specific attributes name

Tags: javascript, json

I need to read my input data from a json file  that has this format:

```
{"object" : {
    "name": "blah",
    "shapes":[
        {
            "filename": "blahlah",
            "materials":[
                {
                    "texture": "blahblahblah"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}}
```

I am using JSON.parse() function to create the object after getting it from the file:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(getJsonFile('file.json'));
```

where getJsonFIle function looks like this.

```
function getJsonFile(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false);
    req.send(null);
    return req.responseText;
}
```

So when i am accessing the elements that i need i take them by going down the children obj.object.shapes[0].filename .

My problem is that I have tried to change the name of one field from the json file, lets say shapes to shapes2 and then proceeded to retrieve the attribute that i needed with the new changed version obj.object.shapes2[0].filename and it does not work. I did my research and in my opinion it should work, and i don't understand why it does not. I don't think i need to use special key words or anything am i right?

Comment: Maybe a caching problem? Clear your browser's cache.

Comment: i have tried that also and it does not work: obj.object.shapes2 is undefined is the error that shows up each time

Comment: `console.log(obj)`, what do you get?

Comment: If it's not the cache, then your object doesn't have that property and you didn't make the changes you thought you've made.